# If $f_k\to f$ uniformly and $\alpha$ is increasing, then $\int_a^x f_kd\alpha \to \int_a^x fd\alpha$ uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f_k,f,\alpha:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$. Suppose $f_k\to f$ uniformly, $f_k,f \in \mathcal R(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ is increasing.
>
> Show that $$\int_a^x f_kd\alpha \to \int_a^x fd\alpha$$ Uniformly.

**Attempt.**

We have to show that given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $|\int_a^xf_nd\alpha-\int_a^xfd\alpha|=|\int_a^x(f_n-f)d\alpha|<\epsilon$, for all $x$.

Now, given $\epsilon$, there exists a $K$ such that $k>K$ implies that $|f_k-f|<\frac {\epsilon}{\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)}$, then 
\begin{align}
\big|\int_a^x(f_k-f)d\alpha\big|&<\big|\int_a^x \frac {\epsilon}{\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)}d\alpha\big|\\
&=|\frac {\epsilon}{\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)}\cdot (\alpha (x)-\alpha(a))|\\ &\leq \frac {\epsilon}{\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)}\cdot(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))=\epsilon
\end{align}

And thus $\int_a^xf_kd\alpha$ converges to $\int_a^xfd\alpha$ uniformly.

A missing case is $\alpha(b)=\alpha(a)$, but then $\alpha$ is constant, and all the integrals are $0$.

Is this correct?

I've used the inequality $$f<g\implies \int f d\alpha < \int g d\alpha$$ but I only know for sure that this is true for riemann integrals, does it still work here?

Comment: You need to replace $<$ with $\le$. But otherwise it looks fine

Comment: I don't understand what means "$\alpha$ is increasing". and if $f_k(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^x f_k(x) dx \to \int_a^x f(x) dx$ uniformly on $[a,b]$, the proof is straightforward (with the $\epsilon$ probably as you did)

Comment: @user1952009 it is a Riemann stieltjes integral

Comment: @user1952009 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: @user251257 Why is that?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD for $<$ you need some continuity assumptions

Comment: Did you want to just assume that $f$ is integrable?  More generally, if $f_n$ is integrable and the sequence converges uniformly to $f$ then it must be the case that $f$ is integrable.  Without simply assuming, that would need to be shown before proving that the limit and integral can be interchanged.

Comment: Yes, I'm just assuming that $f$ is integrable (that's what I meant by $f_k,f\in \mathcal R(\alpha)$). Although I was not aware of that, could you provide a link or reference to a proof of that fact? It seems pretty interesting.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD:  Added a brief proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrability of $f$ can be proved as follows.

Choose $n$ such that $|f_n(t) - f(t)| < \epsilon$ for all $t \in [a,x].$  Since $f_n$ is integrable (with $x$ fixed) there is a partition $P_1$ of $[a,x]$ such that if $P$ and $Q$ are refinements of $P_1$ we have for any Riemann-Stieltjes sums

$$|S(P,f_n,\alpha)-S(Q,f_n,\alpha)| < \epsilon.$$

We also have

$$|S(P,f_n,\alpha)-S(P,f,\alpha)] < \sup|f_n-f|[\alpha(x)-\alpha(a)]< \epsilon[\alpha(x)-\alpha(a)], \\ |S(Q,f_n,\alpha)-S(Q,f,\alpha)| < \sup|f_n-f|[\alpha(x)-\alpha(a)|< \epsilon[\alpha(x)-\alpha(a)].$$

Hence,

$$|S(P,f,\alpha)-S(Q,f,\alpha)| \\ \leqslant |S(P,f,\alpha)-S(P,f_n,\alpha)|+|S(P,f_n,\alpha)-S(Q,f_n,\alpha)|+ |S(Q,f_n,\alpha)-S(Q,f,\alpha)| \\ < \epsilon(1 + 2[\alpha(x)-\alpha(a)]),$$

and $f$ is integrable by the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: Why do the inequalities with the $\sup$s hold?

Comment: Since $|f_n(t) - f(t)| < \epsilon$ for all $t \in [a,x]$ we have $\sup_{t \in [a,x]}|f_n(t)-f(t)| < \epsilon$. Now apply this to the difference of Riemann-Stieltjes sums using the same intermediate points for $f$ and $f_n$.

Comment: $|S(P,f_n,\alpha) - S(P,f,\alpha)| = |\sum_{j=1}^n[f_n(\xi_j)-f(\xi_j)][\alpha(t_j) - \alpha(t_{j-1})]| < ...$